# printing a nested list by a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-lists

I need to print a nested list by using a while loop. any use of a for loop will give a penalty.
My function's output doesn't match the required output.

For example:

```
print_names2([['John', 'Smith'], ['Mary', 'Keyes'], ['Jane', 'Doe']])
```

prints out (required output):

```
John Smith 
Mary Keyes 
Jane Doe
```

My function:

```
def print_names2(people):
    name = 0
    while name < len(people):
        to_print = ""
        to_print = people[name]
        print(to_print)
        name += 1
```

prints out:

```
['John', 'Smith']
['Mary', 'Keyes']
['Jane', 'Doe']
```

How can i remove the lists and the strings?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: Try replacing print(to_print) for print("{0} {1}".format(to_print[0],to_print[1]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this `people[name]` gives a list & that's why you are seeing list in the output. You have to fetch the element of people[name] list.

```
def print_names2(people):
    i = 0
    while i < len(people):
        print " ".join(people[i])
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use two nested while loopls:

```
def print_names2(people):
    i = 0    
    while i < len(people):
        sub_list = people[i]
        j = 0;
        while j < len(sub_list):       
            print(sub_list[j], end=' ')
            j += 1;
        i += 1


print_names2([['John', 'Smith'], ['Mary', 'Keyes'], ['Jane', 'Doe']])    
# John Smith Mary Keyes Jane Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print '\n'.join([" ".join(i) for i in people])
```

or

change your `print(to_print)` to `print(" ".join(to_print))`

Comment: "using while loop" only.